# PHP: __call not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, naming, magic-methods

I'm having a problem creating a class called `API_Widgets` in WordPress using the magic `__call` function. If I simple rename the file to `derp.php` and the class to `API_Derp` then it works without problems.

The following example has been stripped of everything unimportant to this issue (so if there is any error other than the specific fatal error specified in the third code block, ignore it).

Please keep in mind that I know the `core.php` or `API` class' `__call` works, as renaming the `widgets.php` or invoking another class works just fine.

core.php:

```
class API {

    function __call( $method, $args ) {

        $rmethod = "API_{$method}";
        if ( !class_exists( $rmethod ) ) {

            $lmethod = strtolower( $method );
            require_once( "{$lmethod}.php" );

        }

        return new $rmethod( $args );

    }

}
```

widgets.php:

```
class API_Widgets {

    private $widgets = array();

    function Add( $widgets ) {

        if ( is_array( $widgets ) ) {

            foreach ( $widgets as $widget ) {

                if ( !in_array( $widget, $this->widgets ) )
                    $this->widgets[] = $widget;

            }

        } else
            $this->widgets[] = $widgets;

    }

}
```

api.php:

```
$api = new API();
$widgets = $api->Widgets(); // Fatal error: Class 'API_Widgets' not found in /home4/goldencr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/minecraft-api/api/core.php on line 25
//$widgets->Add( 'some_widget' );
```

Comment: I don't get an error when I run it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6pvBi9

Comment: Did you also see `include` file_not_found problem? You could try to use absolute path like `__DIR__.$lmethod.".php"`.

Comment: The absolute path fixed my problem. I use absolute paths everywhere else, I just didn't know it wasn't being used here. Make an answer and I'll accept it as the answer. @Passerby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

Though not hinted at your question, it seems you may not actually included the `widgets.php`. Try to use absolute path to fix that:

```
require_once( __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$lmethod.".php" );
```